# Is it possible to expose S3 storage via standard mechanism (i.e. a filesystem path)?

Tags: php, perl, upload, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I need to upload files from web browser to S3.

I evaluated many upload components and found something that I really like: a CGI program called [FileChucker](http://encodable.com/filechucker/).

The only problem is, this program is geared toward upload to servers, not S3.

I'd like to upload **directly** to S3/EC2, I don't want to upload files to my server and *then* send them to S3

I contacted FileChucker authors asking about compatibility with S3/EC2, they said:

> I'm not familiar with how S3/EC2 work on the backend, but FileChucker can be installed on any server that supports standard web technologies (namely Perl CGI), and it can save its uploaded files to any path accessible via that server.  So if EC2 supports Perl, and if it exposes its S3 storage via the standard mechanism (i.e. a filesystem path), then it should work fine.

It's been few days since I started investigating about S3/EC2, so I can't say for sure. Can someone tell me if this condition is met?

> if EC2 supports Perl, and if it exposes its S3 storage via the standard mechanism (i.e. a filesystem path), then it should work fine.

I believe EC2 does support perl, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use a bog-standard HTTP `<form>` POST to an S3 bucket.

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

Some FTP clients also allow you to upload to S3. On the Mac, Transmit is one such client.

There's also [S3FS](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) if you want to mount an S3 bucket as a filesystem on Mac/Linux.